# printf does not output char array in C

Tags: c

I have a problem with my C program not outputting the string stored in my `buffer[ ]` array.

My code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main()
{
  int textSize = 20;

  int index, ch;
  int count = 0;
  int upperCount = 0;
  int lowerCount = 0;
  char buffer[textSize];

  FILE *pToFile = fopen("input.txt", "r");   

  if (pToFile != NULL)
  {
    while (!feof(pToFile))
    {    
      /* Read in a single line from "stdin": */
      for(index = 0; (index < textSize) && ((ch = fgetc(pToFile)) != EOF)
                      && (ch != '\n'); index++) {
        if(islower(ch))
        {
          buffer[index] = toupper(ch);
          count++;
          upperCount++;
        }
        else if(isupper(ch))
        {
          buffer[index] = tolower(ch);
          count++;
          lowerCount++;
        }
        else
        {
          buffer[index] = (char)ch;
          count++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  fclose(pToFile);      

  /* Terminate string with null characters: */
  buffer[index] = '\0';

  /* Print output out onto screen */
  printf("%s\n", buffer);
  printf("Read %d characters in total, %d converted to upper-case, %d to lower-case\n", 
                             count, upperCount, lowerCount);
  return 0;
}
```

The first `printf` statement does not print, however the second one does.
Please could anyone help explain why this is the case?

Comment: [why `while(!feof(pToFile))` is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: What does the second `printf` called? Is the output of that what it should be? What is the input (the file)? And please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong).

Comment: Oh, and you should really learn how to use a debugger so you step through the code line by line and then be able to easily find out the problem yourself.

Comment: I see no reason to believe that the first `printf` fails to print, but I could believe that it does not print what you expect.  I could especially believe that it prints zero or more non-printing characters (maybe spaces and/or tabs) followed by a newline.

Comment: Every time you start processing a new line, you set `index` back to `0`. When you finally read `EOF` after the last newline, `index = 0`, so you do `buffer[0] = '\0';`, so there's nothing to print.

Comment: The first `printf` will only print something if the file doesn't end with a newline. Then it will print that last line.

Comment: `index < textSize` --> `index + 1 < textSize`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your with your loops, especially that `while (!feof(pToFile))` loop.

Lets say your text contains a single line line less than 19 characters long, that is terminated by a newline. That last bit, the line ending in a newline is important.

What happens when you read the file is that you encounter the newline, break the inner `for` loop and you are back in the outer loop. Because we have not passed the end of the file yet `feof(pToFile)` will return false, and you go back to your `for` loop.

This time in the `for` loop the very first time you call `fgetc` it will notice that you are at the end of the file and return `EOF` and you break out of the loop. However, because your initializing expression in the `for` loop is `index = 0` you will exit the loop with `index` being equal to zero.

Now the file is at its end, and `feof(pToFile)` will return true, and you exit the outer loop, and then you terminate the string in buffer with `index` being zero, i.e. you do

```
buffer[0] = '\0';
```

Now you have an "empty" string that you print.

The simple solution? Skip the outer `while` loop, you don't need it.

Comment: Thank you so much!